# How to query multiple properties from Hubspot using Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, hubspot

I am trying to query all deals from Hubspot with dealstage and dealname properties. I can query all deals with either individual property as part of my parameter_dict, but I can't get multiple. Using the code from Hubspot's documentation as a template, I have the following:

```
    # (Set up connections and parameters above)
    parameter_dict = {'hapikey': hapikey, 'limit': limit, 'properties': 'dealstage', 'properties': 'dealname'}

    has_more = True
    while has_more:
        parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameter_dict)
    # (rest of the code is iterating through and querying everything; nothing different from the code on the site's documentation)
```

The issue is, when I do this, all I get is the dealname. The documentation said I needed to include the properties field multiple times, once for each property, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the need to insert a property parameter multiple times in the contacts API.

The CRM API description for the deals endpoint explains the properties parameter for deals like this:

> String[]
> A comma separated list of the properties to be returned in the response. If any of the specified properties are not present on the requested object(s), they will be ignored.

https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/deals

Try

`parameter_dict = {'hapikey': hapikey, 'limit': limit, 'properties': ["dealstage", "dealname"]}`